# Playing Dynamic loaded SWF AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have 15 empty movie clips on the stage which load a swf into each at runtime from an array

i dont know which SWF is in wich movieclip, and the array has 155 SWF's in it, including duplicates.

My question is how to play the swf in empty movieclip 4 or empty movieclip 6

```
               emptymovieclip1.play(this loaded movie)
```

i dont know his name and i dont want to reference him by the key value from the array

Comment: What's your code for loading the swf ?

Comment: myMovies:Array = new Array("movie1.swf", "movie2.swf")ect http://www.gamezslave.com/game/Slots.swf basically this is done with php and flash, so i want to target the movieclip inside the slotmachine payline instead of typing its direct filepath

Comment: Sorry not talking about the clip names, but how you load them into a MC... Or are you loading a clips that loads a clip ??

Comment: one main movie loads 155 clips into the array, so i f i want to access them i just call the array holderMC.addChild(myMovies[1]) to acess this movie i can call on the timeline myMovies[1].gotoAndPlay(1);// but instaed of writing that out 155 times i want to know how to just play what ever movie i have put into the holderMc at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to put the reference of the movie in the array as well, like :

```
var loader:Loader;
var urlReq:URLRequest;
for(var i:uint = 0 ; i < myMovieClips.length; i++){
      //do your loading of your clips here
      loader = new Loader();
      urlReq = new URLRequest(myMovieClips[i]); //like myClipX.swf
      loader.load(urlReq);
      mcHolder.addChild(loader);
      myMovieClips[i] = loader;
 }
```

Then you can access your clip inside the loader like

```
 var clip:MovieClip = myMovieClips[5].content as Movieclip
```

Comment: lol im sorry if ididnt explain enough, i know how to reference the loaded SWF thats not my problem the question is to reference the movie inside the holder mc, imagine 6 empty movieclips i then load 6 swf into them out of an array which has 155 SWF's... I dont know which movies are  in any of the 6 movieclips cause there randomly placed there, so how can i make movieholder1 just play what ever movie is in there. basically onenterframe movieholder1.play(what ever swf is in here);

Comment: Then you have no choice but save somewhere in an array what you put in that clip ! Something like myMovieClips[i].clips = new Array() then push into myMovieClips[i].clips.

Comment: i think i may have worked it out, using a loop function to check every value, i will post the answer if im correct, for now i will accept your answer